# finding Inverse of a real function which has integral term in it

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined on the interval $(-5,5)$ such that $e^{-x}f(x)=2+\int_0^x\sqrt{t^4+1}\,dt$ for all $x\in(-5,5)$. Let $f^{-1}(x)$ be the inverse function of $f(x)$. Find $\left(f^{-1}\right)^\prime(2)$.
I tried to solve by differentiating the equation but couldn't proceed further. Please help me solve this.

Comment: e^(-x) (f'(x) - f(x) ) = sqrt(x^4 + 1)   . Then I have added the given function with this.

Comment: Seems like a tough one. Ultimately, you need $g(x)$ with $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$.

Comment: Notice that $f(0)=2$.

Comment: then we get f'(0) = 3

Answer (score 1):

let $f(g(x))=x$ where $g(x)$ is the inverse function. Differentiating we have $f'(g(x)).g'(x)=1$ now we want value of $g'(2)$. we also know that $f(0)=2$ so we can write $f'(g(f(0))).g'(2)=1$ as g and f are inverse we have $f'(0).g'(2)=1$ now from the given equation we can find $f'(0)$ which is $3$ hoping for this problem we have $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ hence $g'(2)=\frac{1}{3}$.